# Crystal Report Dynamic parameter prompting user name and password

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I am using CR 2008. That version allows the use dynamic parameters instead of static parameter. Using that type of parameter will direct CR to go inside the table/view and display what is resided inside the database for us to select the data/information for filtering. That is nice and convenient feature but each time I run the report, I was prompted with server name, user name and password. The user name is the name of the schema and its related password. Those credentials are not supposed to be disclosed to users.

Have anyone come across the same issue and how do you stop CR report from asking for these credentials? It did not ask when I switch to static parameters... the prompt only shows up when dynamic parameters are used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to get around this issue. In my Crystal report, I used SQL statement in the command for easy future maintenance. I think using command triggers the prompt for user name and password when dynamic parameters is used. I switched to use views for my reports and CR stopped asking me for the credentials. I still favor using commands instead of views though and still curious if there is a way to stop CR from prompting for credential in dynamic parameters when command is used.

Answer (score 0):

Are facing this issue in CR tool or in any other environment which is used to view the report.

Comment: The report was viewed in other environments.